# Independence and truth in PA

Tags: lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic, independence-results

By $\textbf{PA}$ I will mean the usual first-order Peano Arithmetic. I will denote an element of $\mathbb{N}$ by $n$, and by $[n]$ I will denote the corresponding term in the language of $\textbf{PA}$: $\underbrace{1+1+\dotsb+1}_{\text{$n$ times}}$.

Let $P(x)$ be a recusive predicate defined in $\textbf{PA}$, and let $\theta$ be the sentence $(\forall x)(P(x))$.

Suppose that this sentence $\theta$ is independent from $\textbf{PA}$, that is, $\textbf{PA} \nvdash \theta$ and $\textbf{PA} \nvdash \neg \theta$. Then it follows that $\mathbb{N} \models \theta$. For otherwise, we would have $\mathbb{N} \models \neg \theta$, and hence, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we would have $\mathbb{N} \models \neg P(n)$. Since $n$ is a standard natural number and $P(x)$ is recursive, this would imply that $\textbf{PA} \vdash \neg P([n])$ — contradicting the independence of $\theta$.

An often discussed example of the above situation is the following one: if Goldbach's Conjecture is independent of $\textbf{PA}$, then it is true (that is, it holds in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$).

My question is the following:

For what kind of predicates $P(x)$ definable in $\textbf{PA}$ does the independence of the sentence $(\forall x)(P(x))$ from $\textbf{PA}$ imply that $\mathbb{N} \models (\forall x)(P(x))$?

Note: I have only a modest knowledge of mathematical logic, so I apologize in advance if this question turns out to have a trivial answer.

Comment: Since instances would include any contradictory $P$ and any $P$ for which all standard instances are true, we shouldn't expect a characterization based on logical complexity.

Comment: For common syntactic classes of formulas, this holds for $\Pi_1$ formulas, but (or rather: *consequently*) it fails for $\Sigma_1$ formulas.

Comment: More precisely, it holds for all $\Pi_1$ formulas, and fails for some $\Sigma_1$ formulas.